# How to deal with spaces in image source

Tags: angularjs

I have a lot of images that unfortunately have spaces in their URL's. These are submitted through user input in another system and saved to a database.

I'm having a problem with angular's management of image sources. It doesn't seem to like spaces or "%20" in the ng-src or src attributes.

This

```
 <img ng-src="{{smallImg}}" alt="" />
```

Will output this

```
 <img ng-src="" alt="" />
```

While this

```
 <a href="{{smallImg}}">HERE</a>
```

will output this

```
 <a href="http://example.com/path to my/image with/spaces.jpg">HERE</a>
```

Is there a way to do this without having to go back and rename all these folders?

Comment: you can try the `linky` filter from `ngSanitize`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

Comment: How would that work? I'm pretty new to angular and this is my first major stumbling block on it

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer, it is working for me. 
You can get this like:-

```
    $scope.smallImg = "http://example.com/path to my/image with/spaces.jpg";
```

when you bind this do like

```
    <img ng-src="{{smallImg .replace(' ','')}}" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to make `<img>` `src` empty when using %20, but perhaps you're using an older version of Angular.

```
$scope.smallImg = "http://www.google.com/my images here/pic.jpg".replace(/ /g, "%20");
 ...
<img ng-src="{{smallImg}}" alt="Pic goes here" />
```

Here's a working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/hTFw8rAg0CRxDGjROjjp

(tried to find an image on the web that had a space in the name, but no luck)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out it was a secondary plugin, magic360 that was interfering with the image source